# Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Missing 'api-version' request header. Please set this header with the a value of a supported API version

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I tried to execute an API using Invoke-WebRequest method  with powershell in windows, but it return me the message bellow:

> Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Missing 'api-version' request header. Please set this header with the a value of a supported API version. The minimum supported version is 'v1'. The maximum
>   supported version is 'v1'."}

below, that's what i set in my request:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$header = @{
    "X-ApiKeys" = "******2DD1-F002-7059-6138-*****2EEp7mEiWSG86QE="
    "X-Api-Version" = "1"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Headers $Header -Uri https://127.0.0.1:4119/api/computers?api-version=1
```

Someone can help me please?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is it not just asking for a header like `"api-version" = "v1"`? It would help to know what API you are using and the documentation for the specific call.

Comment: change `"X-Api-Version" = "1"` to `"X-Api-Version" = "v1"` instead?

Comment: i changed this parameter it resolved the problem too
thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

To get consistent help, it is better if you precise the API you are trying to contact. Looking at the port, it seems it's for Deep Security.
The error message is telling you the 'api-version' parameter is missing in the headers and lucky for you it also give you the expected value (v1) !

If the API is effectively for Deep Sec, you also have to set your key in an "api-secret-key" parameter (and not X-ApiKeys):

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$header = @{
    "api-secret-key" = "<your secure key>"
    "api-version" = "v1"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Headers $Header -Uri https://127.0.0.1:4119/api/computers
```

Comment: your answer resolved my problem, thank you so much,